# Reading string from excel using xlrd but it is returning an integer value

Tags: python, django, excel-formula

I have a field in excel which is displayed as '#NAME?' but its actual value is a string that is '=+cmSgER4Q10xcjhgkfygvBl1UUNil+a2aEJ1'. when I am trying to read this field using xlrd it is returning an integer value instead of the actual string. please help me out.

```
import xlrd
import boto3
import pprint

loc = ("C:/cloud/crm.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
ID = (input("Please enter the Customer  ID: "))
for j in range(sheet.ncols):
    if(sheet.cell_value(0,j).strip().casefold() == "AWS Account ID".strip().casefold()):
        for i in range(sheet.nrows):
            if(str(sheet.cell_value(i,j)).strip().lstrip("*").split('.')[0] == ID.strip()):
                username_row_index = i
                break
    
    elif sheet.cell_value(0, j).strip().casefold() == "Access Keys".strip().casefold():
        Key_column_index = j
        
Key = sheet.cell_value(username_row_index,Key_column_index)

print(Key)
```